# Running Dymola parallel on the cluster

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to run Dymola on the cluster so that everyone in my research group could submit a model and simulate jobs, is it possible to run Dymola on a cluster and utilize the power of HPC?

I could use some flags to make Dymola run parallel on a many-cores computer, but how to run a parallel simulation on many computers?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parallelization on a single computer:**

Parallelizing a Modelica model is possible, but the the model needs to be

- suitable by nature (which doesn't happen too often, at least to my experience), for some examples where it works well see e.g. [here](https://ep.liu.se/ecp/096/038/ecp14096038.pdf)
- modified manually by the modeler to allow parallelization, e.g. by introducing delay blocks, see [here](https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/decouple-blocks-and-model-parallelisation/) or some similar approach [here](https://openmodelica.org/publications/CPC2013-sjoelund.pdf).

Often Dymola will output `No Parallelization` in the translation log, presumably due to the model not allowing parallelization (efficiently). Also the manual states: *It should be noted that for many kinds of models the internal dependencies don’t allow efficient parallelization for getting any substantial speed-up.*

I'm not an expert on this, but as to my understanding HPC depends on massive parallelization. Therefore, models generated by Dymola do not seem to be a very good application to be run on HPC-clusters.

**Dymola on multiple computers:**

Running a single Dymola-simulation on multiple computers in parallel is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are several answers to this question.

- The flags under Translation all refer to parallelized code inside a
  single simulation executable. If you mention HPC I do not think you
  need to consider this.
- To run multiple simulations on a single
  multi-core computer there is built-in support in Dymola. The relevant
  function is `simulateModelMulti`, etc. The Sweep Parameters feature uses this automatically.
- There is no built-in support
  to distribute the simulation on several computers in a cluster.
  However, if you generate your dymosim.exe with the Binary Model
  Export option enabled, it can be run on other computers. You need to
  distribute `dymosim.exe`, `dsin.txt` and and data files you read across
  the cluster. I'm sure your HPC cluster has tools for that.